# Limite URL HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

Alguém poderia me dizer se existe alguma limitação para o tamanho de uma URL no  httpclient em Angular?

Estou tentando chamar uma api pela url abaixo, mas os últimos 6 caracteres são cortados.

```
http://localhost/api_cco/ifix/return1tag.php?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI3YWQ2YjMwNy03NTQwLTQ5NzQtOWY1OS01NWY5MjUzMGNjMzYiLCJzdWIiOiIzODIxNDZhNy1hYTkwLTRmMjgtYjYwNC00ZWNkZDJlNDBiN2EiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJoaXN0b3JpYW5fcmVzdF9hcGkucmVhZCIsImhpc3Rvcmlhbl9yZXN0X2FwaS53cml0ZSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJoaXN0b3JpYW5fcHVibGljX3Jlc3RfYXBpIiwiY2lkIjoiaGlzdG9yaWFuX3B1YmxpY19yZXN0X2FwaSIsImF6cCI6Imhpc3Rvcmlhbl9wdWJsaWNfcmVzdF9hcGkiLCJncmFudF90eXBlIjoicGFzc3dvcmQiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMzgyMTQ2YTctYWE5MC00ZjI4LWI2MDQtNGVjZGQyZTQwYjdhIiwib3JpZ2luIjoidWFhIiwidXNlcl9uYW1lIjoiUkVTVFVzZXIiLCJlbWFpbCI6IlJFU1RVc2VyQHViZXJhYmEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NjcwMTM3NjUsInJldl9zaWciOiJmNGVmM2MwMSIsImlhdCI6MTU2NzAxMzc2NSwiZXhwIjoxNTY3MDU2OTY1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvdWFhL29hdXRoL3Rva2VuIiwiemlkIjoidWFhIiwiYXVkIjpbImhpc3Rvcmlhbl9wdWJsaWNfcmVzdF9hcGkiLCJoaXN0b3JpYW5fcmVzdF9hcGkiXX0.OgfDNWitQq5psYLuKFvVV_w5P4kA15IoAXtHvBKx7rtJL9TucWoKKlIxI32DiWzLqGG7g4UZyTV1hdF5KV1WNnDA_x0LcqxEoUOqZo4ndj9940oqOd1bi9Lr7ibm4Jsfau2gEOwZpaiNUkR6cAd3eBISe9LwTXJKYlI63gUMmnC-K_9ZOnuKeOyzhJZKz5IkyuzoKdIQ8kVbGzzAwQaMpAngDr8aIaTjxiPoHjZtGh4XTD3Y0zRv0pdFp-LR3gWzhShxlORIxOGiDzpUd1pAzQKhiZq8lBIjGgQF3e_qK6703EjhofUE5pU2T-Cs9Pbq628Y1kmIW4-V01kyrftAzA&tag=0153_DLD_LD_CCO.05LT07N.F_CV&datai=2019-8-1T00:00:00&dataf=2019-8-1T23:00:00
```

Com o corte o parâmetro dataF acaba ficando sem o ":00:00" gerando erro na consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você acha de usar o enviroment para centralizar suas url?

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBase: 'http://localhost/api_cco/'
};
```

E vejo que isso é uma queryString.. seria bom você usar montar seus headers e params antes de fazer alguma requisição.

```
getHeaders(token: string) {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders();
   this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   this.headers.append('token', token);
   return headers;
}
```

return this.http.get(
             `${environment.apiBase}`, { headers: this.getHeaders() });

Se isso for um token que vc precisa pra todas as requisições já considerou usar um interceptor? e fazer isso por lá?

```
intercept
...
 return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'token': xAccessToken
        }
 });
```